# How to use cURL to upload a file as a GET request

Tags: python, flask, curl

I need to upload a .exe file to a python Flask application as an URL parameter, preferably using cURL. If there is a better way, please tell me.

Comment: Putting the contents of a whole exe file as a URL parameter is a terrible thing to do. Use a POST or PUT with a body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP protocol does not support uploading files using a GET request. You *have*  to use a POST request.